# How read \t in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a text file like this

```
i am a messi fan \t
```

I am using this code to read

```
 f = open(input_para['controle_file'], 'r')
        filedata = f.read().splitlines()
```

now my output is

```
i am a messi fan \\t
```

required output is 
**i am a messi fan \t**

How can I get this exact data from the text file in python?

Comment: I am a Messi fan too. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is based on how python represents a string.  If you `print` it, you should see what you want.

```
>>> r"foo\t"
'foo\\t'
>>> print r"foo\t"
foo\t
```

This boils down to the difference between `repr` and `str` ...

```
>>> s = r"foo\t"
>>> print str(s)
foo\t
>>> print repr(s)
'foo\\t'
```

And the reasoning is that if possible, `repr` should return a string suitable for recreating the object.  In your case, if `repr` didn't add an extra escaping backslash, then the string representation would look like it had a tab character in it.

Comment: i am not doing anything in string. How get same string in file to variable file_data

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo -- I didn't even do that on purpose :)

Comment: @EbinPaulose: you already have that data (ignoring newlines). The difference is in how you display it.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is a `repr` version of the string, you'll not get any `'\\t'` when you use `str` or print that string.

```
>>> strs = "i am a messi fan \t"
>>> repr(strs)
"'i am a messi fan \\t'"

>>> str(strs)
'i am a messi fan \t'
>>> print strs
i am a messi fan
```